# Mobile reputation display different to non-mobile versions

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, down-votes, mobile-web

While browsing StackOverflow on my phone the other day I noticed that when I went to my reputation page it was showing downvotes on questions that do not cost any reputation.

[image]

I was confused by this since I didn't lose any rep (as they were questions) so I checked the desktop version and it does not show the same items under reputation:

[image]

Is this the intended behavior?  Is the mobile version supposed to display downvotes that did not result in a reputation change?  Is this going to be added to the non-mobile version as well?

If it is the intended behavior, please tell me that it is only available for the individual user to see and it is not shown to others.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, downvoting questions shouldn't show in rep history since it doesn't affect rep

Comment: @BenBrocka It seemed like a bug to me considering you don't see the same display on the non-mobile version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mobile should now have the same filter of "don't show 0 change private events" that the main site does, apologies for overlooking this on the mobile views.

Comment: Thanks for fixing this, it bugged me that I could see that.